# Where to clean SharedPrefererences when user closed app directly?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android and java. I tried SharedPreferences to manage session. Once I login into screen I writing below code.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("login", true);
editor.commit();
```

When I closed the app and started again, it directly going to home screen without asking the credentials. 
I dont know where to write these below lines:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

I want to clear the SharedPreferences even if the app closed directly. I tried with finalize but it didn't worked.

**EDIT**:

I add below code to my file. It is working but giving error.

code:

```
protected void onStop() {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("login", false);
            editor.commit(); 

    }
```

Error:

```
android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.ec.testtab/com.ec.testtab.Tabs} did not call through to super.onStop()
```

Comment: Closed means? Using back button?

Comment: @Nabin, no, holding home button for a secon and swiped the app to a side

Comment: "it directly going to home screen without asking the credentials". what do you want exactly? If user logged once then if you started app again don't want to login screen?

Comment: if i destroy the app and started again it has to ask username and pswd @PG_Android

Comment: Lol. After one year I got  -1.

Answer (score 2):

Better to set `prefs` to **false** at your app closed. and when you come back again you just need to check this **prefs** value **true** or **false**.

> false--- means not login
>
> true---- means logined

Comment: my problem is: I killed the app. It is no more running. I started it again. then it directly going logging in without asking password

Comment: @SGG Read my Answer carefully... what you have to do..just set prefs value to false when your app closed(means at Activity Level or at Application Level ) and  when you come back again you checked this prefs value ....if value is false then load your password screen and if not then directly to go Home screen...

Comment: you mean, in onDetsroy method?

Comment: @SGG add `super.onStop()`

Answer (score 1):

I have handeled such things inside these two methods of activity they will be called in your case too so give a try:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Start Logging
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // End Logging
}
```

Comment: I want to clean preferences at onDestroy.

Comment: you are reaching direcly to home screen means onDestroy is not been called look at Activity Life cyle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: add super.onStop(); to your onStop method thats what logcat says

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store shared preferences while your app is getting closed, you should clear your shared preferences every time your app is getting started, so that no previous shared preferences will be there while doing your app's further processes.

Comment: you can clear it in your launcher activity's onCreate() method as soon as it is started.

Answer (score 0):

Once user logged-in into app with valid credentials then only changed share preferences login value to true.

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("login", true);
  editor.commit();
```

And every time on Oncreate just check "login"  value to determine whether user is already logged-in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sharedpreferences is used for **persistent storage**, if u don't need store information for next launcher, use `public static boolean isLogin` maybe an easy way:

```
public static boolean sIsLogin = false;
...
if(doLogin()){
sIsLogin = true;
}
...
```

When u closed the app and started again, `sIsLogin` is false.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can add this lines of code

 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("login", false);
            editor.commit(); 

when your app starts before fetching the username and password from the preferences. So that every time  you start the app it will show login page.
```